# Navigation Bar animation turning white

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

Okay so initially I thought my problem was to do with a new background I was adding. However I have now discovered that actually it just started happening for no reason that I can remember...

The problem that is occurring is when I animate back to my original view where I am hiding my navigation controller bar from my tableview which is displaying my navigation bar. the navigation bar is replaced by a white block.

I am not sure why this is happening.. This is how I have hidden my bar in the view that its animating too..

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO]; //Hides the navigation bar
//..
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view may not be loaded by the time -viewWillAppear is called (come to think of it, it shouldn't be loaded).  Move your implementation into -viewDidLoad.

Edit:  It is because when you hide the navigationBar, your view often doesn't compensate for the height of the bar without the wantsFullScreenProperty being set to YES, and the nav bar set translucent.

Comment: I have now moved both implementations to viewdidload.. however I still have the same problem and its only happening when I animated back to the original View which is the "normal view" code I have listed.

Comment: okay so I have tested without the backgrounds and its doing the same thing..... so now it must be something else...

Comment: I have updated my question to suite whats actually happening.

Comment: The error is happening on the second view. I think I did not explain myself good enough. The first view is hiding the nav bar, the second view is not. when I animate from the second view to the first view the second views navigation bar goes white. If I put the code into viewDidLoad then when I go back to the first view the navigation appears again.

Comment: okay this worked when I put a [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES]; in side viewdidDissapear in the second view :) thanks for the help.